# Angular 2 passing async configuration to component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, angular2-routing

I have a small service to get my config.json: https://pastebin.com/GgWX7FaX

I want to use it in my component so I did

```
import { Config } from '../config/config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  providers: [Config],
```

and

```
  constructor(private _config: Config) {
    this._config.load().then(() => {
      console.log(_config.get('test2')); // working
    });
     _config.get('test2'); // not working
  }
```

So, I want to load the configuration before the component constructor and be able to do this:

```
  constructor(private _config: Config) {
    var url = _config.get('apiUrl')
    var env = _config.getEnv('env')
  }
```

I found a solution that is sadly deprecated on : **https://medium.com/@hasan.hameed/reading-configuration-files-in-angular-2-9d18b7a6aa4**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: No, sorry, I know why this is not working and the fact that the "not working code" doesn't work because it is asynchronous, I'm looking for an angular2 way to load the configuration file and pass it to my component before this component is initialized. someth such a componentResolver

Comment: If it's loaded asynchronously you don't have any other choice rather than to use it inside the callback.

Comment: You can load asynchronous data before hand, this is a lot cleaner ^^ and their is a lot of choices such using router, providers or resolvers

Comment: So? use them :-) Your question is unclear.. You're just loading a config asynchronously and asking why it doesn't work outside of the then function. You should write a more specific answer. And if you are asking whether to use the router, provider or the resolver the answer is it depends and it will attract a lot of opinion based answers.

Comment: Yeah you right, I'll try to implement one of those. Thanks !